# Exclude records with empty binary column data

Tags: mysql, comparison, binary-data

I have a column with type `binary(16) not null` in a mysql table. Not all records have data in this column, but because it setup to disallow `NULL` such records have an all-zero value.

I want to exclude these all-zero records from a query.

So far, the only solution I can find is to `HEX` the value and compare that:

```
SELECT uuid
FROM example
WHERE HEX(uuid) != '00000000000000000000000000000000'
```

which works, but is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried `select uuid from example where uuid is not null`?

Comment: These columns were never setup to allow NULL.

Comment: when you look at the database, do you see blank in the column for these records or null?

Comment: @RahulSharma According to the docs `binary` columns are always padded with `\0`. So inserting an empty string `''` gives N times `\0`. I think that's the problem here. Nice riddle, though. Let's wait for Gordon... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match a `binary` type using a literal, use `\0` or `\1` for the bits.

In your case with a `binary(16)`, this is how to exclude only zeroes:

```
where uuid != '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee2ad/3).

The advantage of using a plain comparison with a literal (like this) is that an index on the column can be used and it's a lot faster. If you invoke functions to make the comparison, indexes will *not* be used and the function(s) must be invoked on every row, which can cause big performance problems on large tables.

Comment: This is even prettier. (_whispers_ and sorry for mentioning Gordon in my comment above ;-))

Comment: I'm just curious: Won't `where uuid!=cast('' as binary(16));` use an index? I mean, it's a constant after all.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT uuid FROM example WHERE TRIM('\0' FROM uuid)!='';
```

Note that Bohemians answer is a lot neater, I just use this when I am not sure about the length of the field (Which probably comes down to bad design on some level, feel free to educate me).

Answer (score 0):

```
select uuid from example where uuid!=cast('' as binary(N));
```

where N is the length of the UUID column. Not pretty, but working.